# passar lista de um método para outro em python

Tags: python, django

Tenho duas funções, preciso que a lista da primeira seja lida pela segunda, as duas ficam em uma view do django, que cada uma gera um template diferente.

```
class Tranfer:
   shared = [] #Essa proprieda sera compartilhada para cada instancia desta 
classe
   def __init__(self, *args):
       self.shared.extend(args)

   def reset(self):
       self.shared = []


def gerar_graficos(request):
    descricao = None
    descricao2 = None

    if request.method=='POST':
        descricao = request.POST['descricao']
        descricao2 = request.POST['descricao2']
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect('banco de dados')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute(consulta.format(descricao, descricao2))
    teste = []
    teste2 = []
    teste3 = []
    teste4 = []
    global dados
    global data
    d = 0
    for line in cur:
        teste.extend(line)
    for indice, c in enumerate(teste):
        #if c + 0 == c:
            teste3.extend([c - 10000])
        #else:
            d = 0
    dados = teste3
    cur.execute(consulta.format(descricao, descricao2))
    for coluna in cur:
        teste2.extend(coluna)
    for indice2, c in enumerate(teste2):
        if indice2 >= d:
            teste4.extend([c])
    data = teste4

    transfer = Tranfer()
    transfer.reset()
    transfer.extend(teste3,teste4)

    y_axis = teste3
    x_axis = teste4
    width_n = 0.001
    bar_color = 'yellow'

    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    context = { 'descricao': descricao, 'descricao2': descricao2 }
    return render(request, 'core/graficos_list.html', context)
```

Passar as listas teste3 e teste4 para a função abaixo.

```
def index(request):
  trans = Tranfer()
  my_list = trans.shared[0]
  my_list2 = trans.shared[1]
  print (my_list)
  fig = Figure()
  ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
  ax.plot(my_list, my_list2)
  ax.grid()
  buf = io.BytesIO()
  canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
  canvas.print_png(buf)
  response=HttpResponse(buf.getvalue(), content_type='image/png')
  return (response)
```

Comment: Rigorosamente falando nesse codigo não tem 2 métodos e sim 2 funcoes, para serem consideradas "metodos" deveriam ser membros de uma classe.

Comment: Por `gerar_graficos` receber `request` como parâmetro, parece-me que ela é uma `view` do Django. Se de fato for, parece-me que as funções `gerar_graficos` e `index` seriam executadas em requisições HTTP distintas e isso pode ser um agravante na sua aplicação dado que o protocolo HTTP, por definição, não retém estado. De qualquer forma a pergunta é bastante vaga, então recomendo que a edite e acrescente mais detalhes sobre o problema.

Comment: editei conforme foi solicitado

Comment: Então elas são executadas realmente em requisições distintas?

Comment: elas são requisições distintas, na verdade cada uma é para ser uma view, mas coloquei as duas na mesma

Answer (score 0):

Basta retornar os 2 elementos da primeira função e usa-lo na função seguinte:

```
def gerar_graficos(request):
    descricao = None
    descricao2 = None
    teste3 = list()
    teste4 = list()
    return (teste3, teste4)

def index(request, graficos):
    fig = Figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    ax.plot(graficos[0], graficos[1])

result = gerar_graficos(request)
index(request, result)
```

Comment: testei a sua solução deu o seguinte erro: index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'graficos'

Answer (score 0):

Caso queira passar uma lista dentro de uma definição **x** para uma definição **y**, saiba que **uma variável criada dentro de uma definição**, é por padrão **local**, ou seja, ela só funciona ali dentro.

Você pode criar uma **variável global** e fazer uma cópia da sua lista, dessa forma, ela se tornara disponível por todo o código. Eu fiz um exemplo que dá erro e em baixo a solução com uma **variável global**, olha só:

```
# Primeira definição
def definicao_1():
    # Lista
    lista_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

    # Apenas para exibir a lista
    print(lista_1)

# Segunda definição
def definicao_2():
    # Tentativa de exibir a lista criada na definição 1
    print(lista_1)

# Chamada da definição 1 para criar a lista
definicao_1() 
# Chamada da definição 2 para tentar pegar os dados dessa lista
definicao_2()
```

Esse código retorna este erro:

> NameError: name 'lista_1' is not defined

Uma das minhas soluções para isso é criar uma variável global, que vai fazer uma cópia da lista na definição 1 e depois torna-la disponível na definição 2

```
# Definição 1
def definicao_1():
    # Essa é a nossa lista
    lista_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

    # Vamos criar uma variável global
    global backup

    # A variável global vai receber a lista
    backup = lista_1

    # Apenas o print padrão
    print(lista_1)

# Definição 2
def definicao_2():
    # Vamos tornar a variável backup disponível nessa definição
    global backup

    # Um print para confirmar que deu tudo certo
    print(backup)

# Chamada da definição 1 para criar a lista
definicao_1()
# Chamada da definição 2 para tentar pegar os dados dessa lista
definicao_2()
```

Aqui retornou esse resultado:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Mas é claro, tem diversas outras formas, mas acho que essa é a mais simples e que exige menos alteração de código.

Comment: Cara repliquei no meu código e da erro, fala que a variável global não foi definida, name 'dados' is not defined criei variavel dados e data ambas globais e joguei no outro método como vc fez, mas apresenta o erro

Comment: Elas estão no mesmo arquivo né?

Comment: Ah e quando você faz isso: "teste1 = ()" Você está declarando uma tupla e não uma lista, portanto use assim: "teste1 = []"

Comment: Estão no mesmo arquivo, e declarei como teste = list() que é uma lista, certo? Mas mesmo assim não foi

Comment: Cara quando você usa o () você está criando um tupla, e tuplas são imutáveis. Seria uma lista se fosse assim: lista = []. Aproveite e mande a mensagem de erro que aparece

Comment: não cara, se to usando teste = () é uma tupla teste = list() é uma lista, mas alterei para como vc falou e deu na mesma, apresenta o erro: name 'dados' is not defined, que foi oq passei como variavel global

Comment: editei a pergunta, pra te mostrar como ficou o código

Comment: Antes de executar a função "index(request)", você está executando a função "gerar_graficos(request)" né? Ah e todo o conteúdo debaixo do "index(request)" está com espaço né?

Comment: sim, exatamente

Comment: Então eu não faço ideia rs, sinto muito por não conseguir ajudar...

Comment: tranquilo, obrigado por tentar

Answer (score 0):

Cara você pode criar uma classe simplesmente para fazer essa transferência, usando as propriedades compartilhadas da classe, veja o exemplo

```
insira o código aqui
class Tranfer:
    shared = [] #Essa proprieda sera compartilhada para cada instancia desta classe
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.shared.extend(args)

    def reset(self):
        self.shared = []

#Usando:
lista1 = [1,2,3,4]
lista2 = [5,6,7,8]
a = Tranfer(lista1,lista2) #Primeira instancia passando os valores

b = Tranfer() #segunda instancia mostrando os valores passados pela primeira
print(b.shared) #[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]

c = Tranfer() #Terceira instancia com o mesmo resultado
print(c.shared) #[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Quando você quiser apagar os valores basta chamar o metodo reset.
Testa ai e ve se funciona, e comenta.

Comment: blz, a classe transfere os valores das listas pra uma variável, mas como eu faço para essa variável ser lida pela outra função? porque eu tenho duas funções diferentes, eu preciso transferir as duas listas de uma função pra outra, como eu faço isso com essa função Tranfer?

Comment: Você vai apenas instanciar a classe novamente onde quer recuperar o valor, e então acessar o atributo "shared".

Na função onde você cria as listas.
1 - Cria a instancia da classe de tranferencia e passa as listas que quer acessar no construtor da classe ja;
      MyClassTransfer(list1,list2,list3)

Quando você for usar essas estas listasem outra função, cria um instancia da classe sem passar paramentro nunhum e acessa o paramentro shared, onde voce adicionou as listas
listas = MyClassTransfer().shared

Comment: eu fiz como vc falou, e apesar de não apresentar mais erros, gerou um gráfico zerado, sem nenhum dado, então acredito que ele gerou duas listas vazias

Comment: Hum, você esta acessando as listas corretamente tipo. ```descricao = Tranfer().shared[0] ```. Pq pela lógica deveria funcionar corretamente pois o valor seria o mesmo para todas as instancia desta classe. Ai quando fosse ultilizar o valor recuperaria com o código ```transfer = Transfer()
descricao = transfer.shared[0]
descricao2 = transfer.shared[1]```

Comment: E assim voce passaria ela como valor para o context do render() ```python
render(request,'seutemplate.html',context={'descricao':descricao, 'descricao2':descricao2})```

Comment: cara, editei a pergunta para o código corrigido, e ele apresenta o erro "list index out of range". E debugando eu vi que a lista fica vazia